# Install license key for plugin

Tags: license

can someone explain how I can install the license of a plugin in my installation?

concretelly I have the craftql license key in https://id.craftcms.com/licenses/plugins and I want to setup that into my installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click link your CraftID to your install, all of your plugin licenses should be automatically configured;  more information at the following:

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/plugins.html#managing-plugin-licenses

Comment: thanks, is there a way to just put it on my repository?